# Iterating Through a Database Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have a model in my database called Item. This is the model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_title = models.CharField("Item title: ", max_length=50)
    item_description = models.CharField("Item description: ", max_length=200)
    starting_price = models.FloatField( default = 0)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'gallery')
    finishTime = models.DateTimeField("Finish time: ")
    ownerID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    higestBid = models.FloatField()
    highestBidderID = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=-1)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

I want to create a function in views.py , which will check the 'active' field of each item in the database. How can I do that?  I have tried to do this:

```
items = list(Item.object.values())
for i in range(items):
  print(item[i].active)
```

However it does not work. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why would you use `values()?` Why would you call `list`? Why would you use `range`? Why are you using an index? Why not just `for item in Item.objects.all(): print(item.active)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the queryset itself:

```
for item in Item.objects.all():
  print(item.active)
```

Please do *not* use [**`.values()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values). You should only use that for some specific cases, like grouping on a certain value. By working with objects, you will still use model objects, and thus certain logic you added on that object, is still accessible.

Furthermore it is often better *not* to use `list(..)`. A `QuerySet` is lazy, and thus if you somehow never iterate over it, then it will not make the query. Furthermore you can then do extra filtering on an existing `QuerySet`.

Comment: Don't use all() if you don't need, it overloads yours db.

Comment: @Unknown123: You can not iterate over `.objects` is a `Manager`, not a `QuerySet`. You need at least `.filter(..)`, `.all(..)`, etc. to construct a `QuerySet`. As the _Zen of Python_ says: _explicit over implicit_.